# Enterprise Keyword term set Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, enterprise-keywords

Can I set an specific term set for the enterprise keyword?
The default Term set is System/Keywords but let's say that I have a enterprise keyword in 2 different content types so in content type A the keywords has an specific meaning and in the Content type B the keywords has a different meaning, so it's there a way to set the term set for an enterprise keyword so I can have the functionality of the field but my final term set is different for each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Keywords feature of SharePoint 2013 is using the OOB term set only.
So I think that your idea can not be realized in that way.